# How do you copy highlighted text in another application to the clipboard? Help explain the 2nd answer please

Tags: c#, clipboard, global

```
SendKeys.Send("^c"); //does not work.
SendKeys.Send("^{BREAK}"); //Also does not work.
SetClipboardData(13 or 7, hWnd); //Also does not work.
SendMessage(GetForegroundWindow(), WM_COPY, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero); (const int WM_COPY = 0x0300;)
SendCtrlC(GetForegroundWindow()); //from http://stackoverflow.com/a/273163/1386831 fails
```

all those fail..

What is the alternative to making a call to `Clipboard.GetData()` when what you're trying to copy is outside of the current application?

Comment: With a simple search i've found that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/273163/1386831

Comment: ps.RedirectStandardOutput = true; was the output of SendKeys.Send(^{BREAK});

Comment: @eyossi that didn't exactly work. SendCtrlC(GetForegroundWindow());

Comment: yeah that isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the window handle of the target control and post a WM_COPY message to it.

Comment: you have an example? i've attempted this multiple times. that all caps COPYDATA or whatever struct and the call, I couldn't get it working, PLEASSSSE get me a working sample... kudos :)

Comment: Not WM_COPYDATA, just plain WM_COPY - takes no arguments: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649022(v=vs.85).aspx. Sorry - don't have an example handy.

Comment: didn't work. const int WM_COPY = 0x0300
SendMessage(nextClipboardAppWindow, WM_COPY, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);

Comment: or SendMessage(GetForegroundWindow(), WM_COPY, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero); didn't work also