# How do I read the contents from an open Windows Console (Command Prompt) using Java Native Access

Tags: java, command-prompt, jna, windows-console

I want to read the text contents of the command prompt window. Let's say, I opened a command prompt, then ran a `dir` command and then `pwd` command. So the problem statement is that, what ever is present in the command prompt I should be able to read them. I am trying to use **Java Native Access** library for achieving this, but didn't get any luck with it. I have tried following code. But I am not getting any output.

```
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.User32;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.HWND;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.RECT;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinUser.WNDENUMPROC;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.HWND;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.LRESULT;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinUser;
import com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.LPARAM;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.WPARAM;

public class NativeExtractor {

    public static void main(String ar[]) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model"));
        executeNativeCommands();
    }

    public static void executeNativeCommands(){
        User32 user32 = User32.INSTANCE;
        //HWND notePadHwnd = user32.FindWindowA("Notepad",null  );
        HWND consoleHwnd = user32.FindWindowA("ConsoleWindowClass",null  );
        HWND editHwnd = user32.FindWindowExA(consoleHwnd, null, null, null);
        byte[] lParamStr = new byte[512];
        LRESULT resultBool = user32.SendMessageA(editHwnd, User32.WM_GETTEXT, 512, lParamStr);

        System.out.println("The content of the file is : " + Native.toString(lParamStr));
    }

    interface User32 extends StdCallLibrary {
        User32 INSTANCE = (User32) Native.loadLibrary("user32", User32.class);
        int WM_SETTEXT = 0x000c;
        int WM_GETTEXT = 0x000D;
        int GetWindowTextA(HWND hWnd, byte[] lpString, int nMaxCount);
        boolean EnumWindows(WinUser.WNDENUMPROC lpEnumFunc, Pointer arg);
        HWND FindWindowA(String lpClassName, String lpWindowName);
        HWND FindWindowExA(HWND hwndParent, HWND hwndChildAfter, String lpClassName, String lpWindowName);
        LRESULT SendMessageA(HWND paramHWND, int paramInt, WPARAM paramWPARAM, LPARAM paramLPARAM);
        LRESULT SendMessageA(HWND editHwnd, int wmGettext, long l, byte[] lParamStr);
        int GetClassNameA(HWND hWnd, byte[] lpString, int maxCount);

        void EnumChildWindows(HWND hwnd, WNDENUMPROC microsoft_word_document, Object o);
    }
}
```

Nevertheless, I can read the text of the notepad using below. But things are not working for command prompt . Please help me in resolving this .

```
public static void executeNativeCommands(){
        User32 user32 = User32.INSTANCE;
        HWND notePadHwnd = user32.FindWindowA("Notepad",null  );
        HWND editHwnd = user32.FindWindowExA(notePadHwnd, null, null, null);
        byte[] lParamStr = new byte[512];
        LRESULT resultBool = user32.SendMessageA(editHwnd, User32.WM_GETTEXT, 512, lParamStr);

        System.out.println("The content of the file is : " + Native.toString(lParamStr));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

A brief survey of other StackOverflow answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21906129/read-all-text-from-external-application) indicate that not all applications respond to the `SendMessage()` function, and the Windows Console (Command Prompt window) is one of those.  While `SendMessage` provides a standard functionality, when it doesn't work you must use the Native API for the program you're trying to read text from; in this case, the Console.

Windows has a complete [Console API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/using-the-console) that includes [numerous functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions) for interacting with the console.  Some console functions are already mapped in JNA's [`WinCon`](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.2.1/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Wincon.html) class which is inherited by `Kernel32`, including the [`AttachConsole`](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.2.1/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Wincon.html#AttachConsole-int-) method to link another PID's console to your process, [`GetConsoleWindow`](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.2.1/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Wincon.html#GetConsoleWindow--) to obtain the handle, and [`FreeConsole`](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.2.1/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Wincon.html#FreeConsole--) when you are done fetching the handle, but to read the contents of the console you'll need to extend the `Kernel32` interface in your own code in order to add more mapped functions:

```
public interface MyKernel32 extends Kernel32 {
    MyKernel32 INSTANCE = Native.load("kernel32", MyKernel32.class, W32APIOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);

    // Mapped functions go here
}
```

Writing the full solution is a bit much for this answer, but feel free to update your question as you attempt to implement this.  You'll need to map the following functions:

- [GetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsolescreenbufferinfoex) (Vista+) or
  [GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsolescreenbufferinfo) (Win2K+) to get the console's buffer
  coordinates (rows and columns) to know how far back you can read
- [ReadConsoleOutput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsoleoutput) to actually copy the contents of the console
  buffer into your own buffer of characters to manipulate

Comment: Have tried the following methods , `WinDef.HWND GetConsoleWindow(); int GetConsoleOutputCP(); boolean AttachConsole(int dwProcessId);`. Didn't get any success. Tried the sample program from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/reading-and-writing-blocks-of-characters-and-attributes. But it's giving **0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000006.**. I have forgot C big time.Am I doing something wrong, please guide me, I am stuck and not able to progress.

Comment: According to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/attachconsole), "A process can be attached to at most one console. If the calling process is already attached to a console, the error code returned is ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED (5)."  Looks like you need to call [FreeConsole](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/freeconsole) to detach from your current console first.