# c++ extract text from edge browser as if using Ctrl+A and Ctrl+C

Tags: c++, winapi, clipboard, tedgebrowser

I am currently extracting text from a website using SendInput Ctrl+A and Ctrl+C then I keep an eye on the clipboard and extract the text. This requires that the EdgeBrowser window have focus, it is that part that doesn't work for my program because the text usually change once every minute.

So my question is: Is there a way to extract the visible text from an EdgeBrowser window without it having the focus ?

P.s. The Edge Browser is embedded into my app via a dll. (c++ Builder component)

Comment: Why not use extension? You can do the same thing very easily by using Javascript

Comment: Thanks Asesh, I'm pretty much strictly c++, so do you have a link to where I can find information on  how to do that ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read all text from external Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21906129/read-all-text-from-external-application)

Comment: Thanks Raymond, but no. First of all the edge window is embedded in my application, but it is done via a dll so it functions as it own process.

Comment: The same technique works for reading from your own process. But since it is your webview, you have other options available, like the ExecuteScript noted in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It only takes two lines of code when using the C++Builder component TEdgeBrowser

One for executing a script on the webpage:

```
EdgeBrowser->ExecuteScript(L"document.body.innerText");
```

And then the result is returned in the ExecuteScript event:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::EdgeBrowserExecuteScript(TCustomEdgeBrowser *Sender, HRESULT AResult, const UnicodeString AResultObjectAsJson)
{
   Memo1->Text = Sysutils::StringReplace( AResultObjectAsJson, L"\\n", L"\r\n", TReplaceFlags()<<rfReplaceAll );
  
}
```

The StringReplace is due to a bug in the JSon string.