# Code for copying the text from another window

Tags: c#

Is it possible to write a code that will copy text values from a window belonging to  another application?

I have an application that gives me live results(only texts), every 5 minutes, and I cannot copy paste them every 5 min.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copy and Modify selected text in different application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235972/copy-and-modify-selected-text-in-different-application)

Comment: unfortunately, no. I want the code to copy a text from a live list that another application provides. and it needs to do it automatically foe example each 10 minutes.

Answer (score 3):

**Maybe**.

It depends on how the target application is exposing its text to the OS.

If the application is using a private 2D/drawing library to render text by itself to an in-memory or in-VRAM buffer, then no. You'll need to grab a screenshot and perform OCR on it - or you could inject your own code into the target process and intercept those 2D/drawing library calls to get the text being rendered.

If the application is using the Windows-provided GDI then there are ways of intercepting those calls to get the text. I believe Direct2D and DirectWrite also offer straightforward ways of intercepting/profiling their calls as well.

If the application is using a GUI framework or platform like WinForms or WPF then there are ways of inspecting the rendered view's object-model to extract data and text - this is how various "Spy" utilities work. "Spy++" (`spyxx.exe` included in Visual Studio and the Windows SDK) can inspect native Win32 `hWnd` windows and "[Snoop](https://github.com/snoopwpf/snoopwpf)" is a very powerful tool for inspecting WPF applications (Visual Studio's built-in Visual Inspector does the same thing).

Additionally, often GUI frameworks and platforms will support the OS' built-in Accessibility platform and will expose on-screen data as machine-readable structured data for use by screen-readers for the blind and visually impaired as well as automation software. Windows' built-in platform is called [Active Accessibility and Windows UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/microsoft-active-accessibility-and-ui-automation-compared). There are premade tools you can download to inspect Active Accessibility data.

If it's a HTML application (e.g. Windows HTA, Electron app, Chrome desktop app, etc) then that's another topic.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time.
so I ran spyxx.exe and for specified windows:
class name: HwndWrapper[TMain.exe;;e9b5e87f-3be2-4556-baa5-cc269616ef1f]

I'm really new to coding so please kindly excuse my lack of knowledge.
so what is the next step?

Comment: @PeymanJavanbakht `HwndWrapper` indicates the application is possibly using `pywinauto` or WPF. Judging by the screenshot you posted it's likely using WPF, so you can probably get text out of it using Snoop.

Comment: @PeymanJavanbakht Assuming it is a WPF application, then you should be able to programatically get the text using the Windows UI Automation API because WPF automatically exposes its DOM to Windows: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32

Comment: wow, thank you so much, I really appreciate it man.
I will do that now
thanks again

Comment: @PeymanJavanbakht I wish I could look as cool as you in sunglasses

Comment: thank you so much, you are very kind @Dai
dude its really working!!! you are amazing, thank you, so the next step is to use the snoop code source in a c# to create my app???

Comment: @PeymanJavanbakht I wouldn't use Snoop's actual source code - but you should be able to use it as a project-reference (i.e. as a library). That's all I can tell you for now though as I've never actually worked with Snoop - and my time is billable :)

Comment: alright, thank you so much it was very nice talking to you.

Comment: is there anyway that I can contact you to make you an offer to help me write the code?